# C# HttpWebResponse contentlength = -1 when file too large

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm getting a string in a json format from the Rotten Tomatoes website. My code looks like

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    //Code I'm using the reader with
}
```

When I run a movie search that returns 1 - 4 movies it works fine. However, If I try to get the results of 5 or more it won't work. The webResponse contentlength is -1. When I'm returning the results of 4 movies the contentlength is 7,449.

Comment: Does it return an HTTP status code?

Comment: I agree with both of the answers so far from spender and Alexei Levenkov. Banking on N # of movies sounds dangerous because there is no guarantee of a set content-length per movie. Therefore, implementing something to the effect of "read the entire stream until there is no more" seems to be the way to go. Alternately, if you **CAN** guarantee N length per movie, then you can query in batches of N movies per batch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When contentLength returns -1, this is most likely because the response is being returned in [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) (or possibly http "0.9"). As such, there is no known content-length at the start of the transmission. Just read your `StreamReader` until the end, and you'll have everything the server sent to you.

Comment: Just found this out when Fiddler converted a non-chunked response into a stream -- it set the content-length to -1 and the transfer encoding to chunked.

Answer (score 3):

Expected behavior - property returns content length as set by the server, so if that header is not set you get -1 (which is likely behavior for large files that are streamed from server).

[HttpWebResponse.ContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.contentlength.aspx):

> Remarks: The ContentLength property contains the value of the Content-Length header returned with the response. If the Content-Length header is not set in the response, ContentLength is set to the value -1